# Roles account in sql server 2012 database can't login in MVC 4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue logging into to my ASP.NET MVC 4 site that I am developing.

I started off by creating the `Project4DB` by running the command-line `aspregssql` file.

The database was created and I could see it in my SQL Server 2012 Developer edition.

I created a new ASP.NET MVC4 Application.

I configured the site with the Website Configuration Tool and had to change the `web.config` file around for the tool to register.

I successfully created a user from the tool and it did put the user in the database.

I then tried to debug and `login`, but it is not accepting my `login`.  If I register via the site, it lets me `login` with the dummy `credentials` I registered with.

How can I get the site to use the `Project4DB` to `login`, or what am I doing wrong?  Thought I had it after I got the code to work!

Here is my connection string that I have. I commented out the original. And added the `enter code here` name

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MusicStoreEntities" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Project4DB;
                          Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

After creating this, I replaced the `DefaultConnection` value in the `AccountModel.CS` `dbcontext` class with `MusicStoreEntities`

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("MusicStoreEntities")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

And I also replaced it here in the `SimpleMembershipInitializer` Class.

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
{
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MusicStoreEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
}
```

It is failing here in the `AccountController` saying the password is incorrect, but it is correct in the `Project4DB`.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
}
```

I assume I am not point the app itself to the `Project4DB`(how do I do that)?, or where is it storing the dummy usernames and passwords?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you set a break point on the `Login` method and see exactly the value of `model.Password` when you get the error?

Comment: yes it has the same value that i enter from the `login` form

Comment: what is the password you are using to sign in ?